# MYSQL JAVA , Adding Values and and displaying auto-incremented number

Tags: java, mysql

```
if(i > 0){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Saved With ID = " + rs.getString("ID")); 
}
```

I am adding some value to database, I can add easily. There is no option for adding ID to database (as it will be auto incremented within database). But after the data is added, I want to get the auto incremented ID number from database.

`if(i>0)` that is if data was added successfully.

Adding to database is fine, and in database the ID number are also increasing.

Comment: The Problem is this Command is not working. 
i am Getting NULL Pointer error.

Comment: Look into https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html to get the last insert ID. You'll need to return that value to the application.

Comment: That was fast , and very helpful :-)
Thank You

Comment: What about the query "select max(ID) from table;"  And where is "rs.next()"

Comment: I did max(ID). i just needed a direction of what to search. 
Thank You.